# Find Jordan canonical form with Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: K^3\to K^3$ be a map in Jordan canonical form having a matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 &0&1\\
0&1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Find the JCF of the map $f\otimes f$.

My question is, do I really have to do the JCF for a $9 \times 9$ matrix? or I need to use some property of the relationship between JCF of $f\otimes f$ and the JCF of $f$?

Comment: What do you mean by "a map in Jordan canonical form"? Certainly that matrix is not a Jordan canonical form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That matrix is real symmetric, therefore diagonalisable, as it happens with distinct integral eigenvalues, forming the set $\{-1,1,2\}$. Since the Kronecker product of diagonal matrices is diagonal, it follows that $f\otimes f$ is also diagonalisable, with multiset of eigenvalues
$$\{\!\{\,ab\mid \, a,b\in \{\!\{-1,1,2\}\!\}\,\}\!\} =
\{\!\{-2,-2,-1,-1,1,1,2,2,4\}\!\}.$$